# Why is css hover interacting with javascript (fullpage.js) and how can I stop it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, fullpage.js

I am using two plugins, a jquery and css based page scroller called fullpage.js, and a css hover effect that are interacting in an undesirable way. **If the user hovers over one of the images that has the css effect, it somehow triggers the page scroller to activate and move the page.** I do not want this to happen and would like to stop it.  Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/ihatecoding/pen/pyEbqY

I don't know enough about css and javascript to understand why. I have looked at the fullpage.js options, and I couldn't find anything that seemed to work - changing  "autoscrolling" to false didn't help. It may be that the problem is just due to the css of the two plugins interacting, and javascript may not be causing the interaction.

To reproduce the unwanted autoscrolling,

1) scroll so the images in the first section (the team members in "Section 1") are at the top of the page, and half obscured by the top of the window.
2) Hover over one of the team member images, you should see the page move down.

The divs that appear upon hover and which I believe trigger the unwanted scrolling seem to be of class .member__info.

This is the css code for the plugin I used for the hover effect.

```
/* team member css */
$tisa: ff-tisa-web-pro;

$burlywood: #D9BC55;
$title-on-black: $burlywood;

.wrapper--team {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  background-color: #E9E7D0;
}

.l-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
  .l-container {
    max-width: 64rem;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 75em) {
  .l-container {
    max-width: 75rem;
  }
}

.team-grid {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  *zoom: 1;

  &:before, &:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
  }

  &:after {
    clear: both;
  }

}

.team-grid__member {
  font-family: $tisa;

  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem;

  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;

  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
position:relative;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 28em) {
  .team-grid__member {
    width: 49%;
    max-width: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 42em) {
  .team-grid__member {
    width: 32.5%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 62em) {
  .team-grid__member {
    width: 19.45%;
  }
}

//////////////////////
// MODULE GRID
//////////////////////
.team-grid__member {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.team-grid__member img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 8px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
}

.member__info {


  color: #fff;
    height: 86%;
    width: 86%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    left:16px;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
z-index:50;
  }

.member__name {
  color: $title-on-black;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 12px;
}

.member__title {
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1rem;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

a.member__link {
  background: #D68D2C;
  color: #FFF;

  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

// FIX THE TOUCH METHOD
//.no-touch .team-grid__member:hover .member__info,
//.team-grid__member.cs-hover .member__info {
//  opacity: 1;
//}

.team-grid__member:hover .member__info {
  opacity: 1;
}


// ----- Middle Alignment Vertical ----- //
.member__info:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
}

.center-vert-content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* end of current team member css */
```

This is the way I call fullpage.js in my codepen (I use document ready and function in the actual document, but codepen likes it this way):

```
 $('#fullpage').fullpage({
          sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE'],
          scrollBar: true

});
```

This is the link to fullpage.js:

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/jquery.fullPage.js

There is also some css associated with the fullpage plugin that might be relevant:

```
html.fp-enabled,
.fp-enabled body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;

    /*Avoid flicker on slides transitions for mobile phones #336 */
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
#superContainer {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;

    /* Touch detection for Windows 8 */
    -ms-touch-action: none;

    /* IE 11 on Windows Phone 8.1*/
    touch-action: none;
}
.fp-section {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari<=5 Android<=3 */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* <=28 */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.fp-slide {
    float: left;
}
.fp-slide, .fp-slidesContainer {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.fp-slides {
    z-index:1;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; /* Safari<=6 Android<=4.3 */
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.fp-section.fp-table, .fp-slide.fp-table {
    display: table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.fp-tableCell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.fp-slidesContainer {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.fp-controlArrow {
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* webkit (safari, chrome) browsers */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* mozilla browsers */
    -khtml-user-select: none; /* webkit (konqueror) browsers */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-top: -38px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
.fp-controlArrow.fp-prev {
    left: 15px;
    width: 0;
    border-width: 38.5px 34px 38.5px 0;
    border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
}
.fp-controlArrow.fp-next {
    right: 15px;
    border-width: 38.5px 0 38.5px 34px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
}
.fp-scrollable {
    overflow: scroll;
}
.fp-notransition {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
}
#fp-nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    margin-top: -32px;
    top: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
#fp-nav.right {
    right: 17px;
}
#fp-nav.left {
    left: 17px;
}
.fp-slidesNav{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
}
.fp-slidesNav.bottom {
    bottom: 17px;
}
.fp-slidesNav.top {
    top: 17px;
}
#fp-nav ul,
.fp-slidesNav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#fp-nav ul li,
.fp-slidesNav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 14px;
    height: 13px;
    margin: 7px;
    position:relative;
}
.fp-slidesNav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#fp-nav ul li a,
.fp-slidesNav ul li a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#fp-nav ul li a.active span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li a.active span,
#fp-nav ul li:hover a.active span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li:hover a.active span{
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
    border-radius: 100%;
 }
#fp-nav ul li a span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li a span {
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 4px;
    width: 4px;
    border: 0;
    background: #333;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -2px 0 0 -2px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
#fp-nav ul li:hover a span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li:hover a span{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: -5px 0px 0px -5px;
}
#fp-nav ul li .fp-tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#fp-nav ul li:hover .fp-tooltip,
#fp-nav.fp-show-active a.active + .fp-tooltip {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    width: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
#fp-nav ul li .fp-tooltip.right {
    right: 20px;
}
#fp-nav ul li .fp-tooltip.left {
    left: 20px;
}
.fp-auto-height.fp-section,
.fp-auto-height .fp-slide,
.fp-auto-height .fp-tableCell{
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not reproduce your problem on Chrome with the link you provided. Hovering the images does nothing at all.

It seems your problem might be related with `fitToSection:true`. Try turning it off. )(option `fitToSection:false`)
In any case, if you have bigger section than the viewport you should be using `scrollOverflow:true` and `scrollBar:false`.

Otherwise, your only solution is to use `autoScrolling:false`.

Comment: You go got it!!!    I am using Chrome, so I am not sure why you couldn't reproduce it the behavior,  perhaps you didn't scroll the page so the images were at the top? Regardless: as the author of the script you correctly understood which part of the code could stop this.  When I change the setting of "fitToSection" to "false", as you suggested, the behavior stops. Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** My apologies. I realize that the answer that refers to fitToSection:false from Alvaro actually does what you want. I was mislead by the fact that hovering over the image had nothing to do with the auto fit to section feature.

**Original:**
What you are describing as your problem seems to be exactly what fullPage.js was written to do. Fullpage moves the scrollbar so that what you see is one of its valid sections.

What setting autoScrolling: false in your fullpage initializer does is entirely different. When autoScrolling is set to true then one move of the mousewheel will scroll an entire section down or up. When it is set to false, your mousewheel will move normally but in each case 1 second after you have stopped scrolling, fullPage will move the window to its correct section.

Comment: I like the plugin because I like the animated scrolling functionality that this plugin provides 1)with the keyboard or 2) when clicking to a link. But this hover effect is destroying my page experience.  My actual team member section is much bigger (it has 15 people), and the hover interactions with fullpage make you unable to view the members.  When you hover over one of them to see their details it scrolls ahead to the section below. Making all team members suddenly invisible. No bueno. :)  Do you have another solution?